# sympy returns TypeError when putting irrational in a fraction

Tags: python-3.x, typeerror, sympy

I have tried to put this in sympy, but it doesn't work:

```
import sympy
sympy.init_printing(use_unicode=True)

sympy.Rational(3, sympy.sqrt(3))
```

It returns to me the following:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-25b0450ea0d0> in <module>()
      1 root = sympy.sqrt(3)
      2 
----> 3 sympy.Rational(3, sympy.sqrt(3))

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\numbers.py in __new__(cls, p, q, gcd)
   1488         else:
   1489             p = Rational(p)
-> 1490             q = Rational(q)
   1491 
   1492         if isinstance(q, Rational):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\numbers.py in __new__(cls, p, q, gcd)
   1483 
   1484             if not isinstance(p, SYMPY_INTS + (Rational,)):
-> 1485                 raise TypeError('invalid input: %s' % p)
   1486             q = q or S.One
   1487             gcd = 1

TypeError: invalid input: sqrt(3)
```

Why does this happen? How can I put an irrational number inside a fraction in sympy, then?

Comment: A fraction with (a rational numerator and) an irrational denominator wouldn’t be a `Rational` number, would it?

Comment: try `sqrt(3.)`.

Comment: It gives me a weird fraction (I guess it's an approximation), isn't there a way to pretty print 3 / sqrt(3) in sympy?

Comment: I have found that if I simply write:

    3 / sympy.sqrt(3)

Sympy symplifies it rationalizing the denominator, i.e. returning sqrt(3) prettyprinted

Comment: so what you actually want to do is to prettyprint 3/sqrt(3) ?

Comment: I want sympy to store that expression in a variable so it can simplify it in some way (in this example, I just wanted it to rationalize the denominator)

Answer (score 1):

To create the ratio, use `3/sqrt(3)`; to print it as such requires the use of unevaluated expressions: `(Mul(3,Pow(sqrt(3),-1, evaluate=False),evaluate=False)`.